# how do i get the 3 last rows from a table using codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, get

i have a function that loads comments from a database. 
in an other page, 
I want to get the 3 last rows from a table in my database(so it would show the last 3 comments). 
that is the function that i have in my model:

```
public function load3Comments(){
            $this->db->order_by("c_id", "desc");
            $query = $this->db->get('comment');
            return $this->get_results($query);
        }
```

Comment: Be a bit more descriptive. What is the output of this function? What was the expected output? This by itself doesn't tell us very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function load3Comments(){
            $this->db->order_by("c_id", "desc");
            $this->db->limit(3);
            $query = $this->db->get('comment');
            return $this->get_results($query);
        }
```

That should do it. THere's a function for it in CI. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html